# how to take first value from dataset from given dataset

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, dataset

I am using VB.NET

I have following code:

```
ds = gc.GetDataToListBinder("select distinct(tabname) tabname from Parameteronline where isactive='Y'")
```

ds is dataset containing only one column and 5 rows.

I just wanted to take first value from this dataset.

I tried:

`dds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Cells(0).toString()` but this is not giving me value.

I use to take value from dataset in C#.

How should i take it from vb.net

Comment: Not giving value means? what is happening?

Comment: You are showing the code where you initialize `ds` (the `DataSet`?) but you are accessing `dds`.

Comment: yes may be dds is some other dataset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below, but make sure your datatable has values:

```
dds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0)
```

Comment: dds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("columnname").toString() in this way it worked

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).ItemArray(0)
```

Comment: ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("columnname").toString() in this way it worked